How to clear modal fields after closing in Javascript?
I'm experiencing an issue with form in a modal. I have a table with customers with the option to edit customer data. When I open the edit modal, all customer data is displayed in form fields for editing. However, when I close the modal and go to open one from another customer, I make the changes and when it is saved, the data of this customer is also saved in those of the first customer. As if the first modal was still active, but hidden. I'll send you the two functions I did.
function detalhesCliente(clienteId) {
    const url = '/editar/' + clienteId + '/';
    const init = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
        },
    };
    fetch(url, init)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(cliente => {
        
            document.getElementById('modalNome').value = cliente.cliente.nome;
            document.getElementById('modalEmail').value = cliente.cliente.email;
            document.getElementById('modalCpf').value = cliente.cliente.cpf;
            document.getElementById('modalTelefone').value = cliente.cliente.telefone;
            document.getElementById('modalEndereco').value = cliente.cliente.endereco;

            
            const veiculosBody = document.getElementById('modalVeiculosBody');
            veiculosBody.innerHTML = '';
            
                cliente.cliente.veiculos.forEach(veiculo => {
                    const row = document.createElement('tr');                    
                    row.innerHTML = `
                        <td><input class="modelo form-control inputs" value=${veiculo.modelo}></td>
                        <td><input class="marca form-control inputs" value=${veiculo.marca}></td>
                        <td><input class="placa form-control inputs" value=${veiculo.placa}></td>
                        <td><input class="ano form-control inputs" value=${veiculo.ano}></td>
                        <td><input class="cor form-control inputs" value=${veiculo.cor}></td>
                        <td><input class="km form-control inputs" value=${veiculo.km}></td>
                        
                    `;
                    
                    veiculosBody.appendChild(row);
                });

                $('#clienteModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    document.getElementById('cliente').reset();
                });

                document.getElementById('btnSalvar').addEventListener('click', function() {
                   
                    salvarEdicoesCliente(clienteId);
                    $('#clienteModal').modal('hide');                 
                    
                }); 

            $('#clienteModal').modal('show');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Erro ao buscar detalhes do cliente:', error);
            
        });
}

function salvarEdicoesCliente(clienteId) {
    const nome = document.getElementById('modalNome').value;    
    const email = document.getElementById('modalEmail').value;    
    const cpf = document.getElementById('modalCpf').value;    
    const telefone = document.getElementById('modalTelefone').value;    
    const endereco = document.getElementById('modalEndereco').value;    


    const veiculos = []
    const veiculosRows = document.querySelectorAll('#modalVeiculosBody tr');
    veiculosRows.forEach(row => {
        const modelo = row.querySelector('.modelo').value;
        const marca = row.querySelector('.marca').value;
        const placa = row.querySelector('.placa').value;
        const ano = row.querySelector('.ano').value;
        const cor = row.querySelector('.cor').value;
        const km = row.querySelector('.km').value;

        veiculos.push({modelo, marca, placa, ano, cor, km});
    });    

    const dadosCliente = {
        nome: nome,
        email: email,
        cpf: cpf,
        telefone: telefone,
        endereco: endereco,
        veiculos: veiculos
    };
  
    fetch('/editar/' + clienteId + '/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dadosCliente)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Dados do cliente atualizados com sucesso.');           

            clientes();            
            
        } else {
            return response.json(); 
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data && data.error) {
            // Exibe a mensagem de erro retornada pelo servidor no modal
            document.getElementById('mensagemErro').innerText = data.error;
            document.getElementById('mensagemErro').style.display = 'block';
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Erro ao enviar requisição:', error);
    });
}


I want the modal to be closed and its fields, so when it opens from another client it doesn't save on top of the previous one.

Put your inputs in a form and reset after use:
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

Have I tried, does he clean the fields?  In this case, my problem is that even if I close the modal, when I open another modal and modify the customer data, this data is also saved on top of the customer data opened in the previous modal.

This is too difficult with this limited infomation. Join my meeting and let me help you now.
https://meeting.tencent.com/p/8785541036

haha. @shrekuu I'm Brazilian, I still don't speak English. But I can send you more details of the code right here.

@JonatasPereira That's all right. I am not an native English speaker. We will use simple English. Still waiting you to join the meeting. It's great to make friends.

@shrekuu Available on Discord .jhonsouza

How about constructing a new modal from a template every time you edit an entry? Maybe not performant, but simple and working.
